# Git - Merge branch from a different repository

Tags: git, merge, branching-and-merging

I hope this does not seem to obvious. I have two git repository. We decided to split one branch from the first repoistry into a git sub module. Now I have been using this sub module, however people have been pushing commits to the first repository into the branch that was made into a sub module.

How can I merge the changes from the branch in the first repository into newly created second repository? (Which we now use as the sub-module)

I have tried adding another remote into the second repo and merging that branch across, using:

```
git remote add otherOrigin git-Blah@blah.blah:originalRepo.git
git merge otherOrigin originalBranch
```

However I get:

```
fatal: 'otherOrigin' does not point to a commit
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two repos, for the given branch (the one split as a sub-module in Repo1, while being kept in Repo2), initially have a **common history**, then it should be possible, in theory, to:

- split the branch in Repo2 as an individual repo
- add that individual repo as a remote of the current submodule repo
- try and perform the merge from there.

But that can quickly become a drag if you have to repeat that process on a regular basis (unless you can script it).

Comment: ...and then whack people over the head for repeatedly messing it up. ;-)

Comment: Sorry I didn't accept this earlier, I was too busy whacking people over the head

Comment: @Graham: no problem. I had answers accepted more than *three* years after being posted ;) And I am not too sure if I want to know what they were busy doing during that time...

Answer (score 1):

clone your repository. Now use filter-branch to just keep the changes to what should be in your submodule. add this repo as a remote of your submodule. fetch the branch from that new remote. Use `git rebase --root --onto` to "place" the changes to some point in the history of your submodule.

Hope this helps.